# Revolution Slider jquery plugin inside Vue.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, revolution-slider

I am trying to convert an html project into a vue app.
The original project uses jquery plugin for Revolution slider by adding them via `script` tag inside html file's `body` tag and later initializing them:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/revolution/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/revolution/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script>
```

**What is the best way to add revolution slider to my vue project?**

I have installed jquery via npm and tried to import these scripts into the main.js entrypoint file. I am not familiar with node or npm. Also when app loads, the jQuery is undefined inside these scripts raising errors in the console, which means there is something wrong.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: Not really. I think I moved to angular and similar packages. The script tag part is not very interesting ;)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to load jquery in the same way (before those two script tags).

Comment: but I already need jquery somewhere else and have installed it via npm. Adding it via script tag would create a duplicate...

Answer (score 0):

Import jQuery into your main.js and then set window.$

```
import $ from 'jquery'
window.$ = $
```

That will make it available globally so the scripts can use `$` in the standard way.